# How to edit a function with a specific environment defined in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to adapt the function `cv.glm` (package `boot`) to my specific needs; Specifically, my predictor variables will need to be slightly adjusted based on the samples used in each permutation. This seemed simple enough to add a few lines to the function and then rename it as my own function ("`cv.glm2`"). Unfortunately, one of the internal functions `sample0` is no longer found in my version:

```
 Error in cv.glm2(DF, glm1, K = 2) : could not find function "sample0"
```

This seems to have something to do with the environment that is defined within the `cv.glm()` function. By printing out the function, I see that the final two lines read:

```
cv.glm
...
<bytecode: 0x0000000010117220>
<environment: namespace:boot>
```

I would like to know how to define my new function's environment to find `sample0`. Or, if there is not a big difference, I could substitute `sample`. Since I can neither see what `sample0` is doing, I am unable to make this call. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are just creating a new function in the `GlobalEnvironment` it doesn't know where to find functions that are not exported from the pacakge of the original function. You just need to tell it explicitly where to find them using the `:::` operator. So e.g.

```
cv.glm2 <-
function (data, glmfit, cost = function(y, yhat) mean((y - yhat)^2), 
    K = n) 
{
    #  // Some other code here //  #

    #  Tell it which package the unexported  function resides in
    s <- boot:::sample0(rep(1L:K, f), n)
}
```

Comment: If the function is not exported, you need three colons: `boot:::sample0`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks to you both, I was just about to ask about the error regarding exportation. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a simple way to see what's happening within the `sample0` function as well?

Comment: Sure... `getAnywhere( sample0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `cv.glm` is your new edited function then try this so that `cv.glm` looks up free objects (such as `sample0`) in the right place:

```
environment(cv.glm) <- environment(boot::cv.glm)
```